# Google Doc Api : download inline object

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-docs-api

I'm creating a Google Doc to HTML converter, I want to use the [Doc Api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) and not export it as HTML using the Drive Api :

```
$service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);
$request = $service->documents->get($docId);

$elements = $request->getBody()->getContent();
```

$elements is an array of Google_Service_Docs_StructuralElement

Looping through paragraph > elements, if there is an inline object, the inlineObjectElement property is set with a Google_Service_Docs_InlineObjectElement

**Question is :** how to get the content of an Google_Service_Docs_InlineObjectElement to save it as a file ?
All we have in this object is an inlineObjectId...

Comment: Did you find a solution? Id also be very interested :)

Comment: I'm sorry you can't without HTML export, which in itself is a hack not guaranteed to work over time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for this on [this blog post](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/integrate-laravel-and-wordpress/).

Basically, all inline elements are located at:

```
$inlineObjects = $request->getInlineObjects();
```

*Btw. I recommend renaming "$request" to "$document"*

Now, with the **inlineObjectId** you can get the particular object you want - and there, you get a **contentUri** which contains the binary content.

Here, a screenshot of `$inlineObjects` contents, which is an assoc array. The key is the inlineObjectId:

[image: Screenshot of the Google_Service_Docs_InlineObject in var dumper]